# What is the cleanest way to count frequencies in python

Tags: python, counting

I have data as following [0.1,0.2,1,5,100] and so on...
What i want to do is count number of items between

```
1-10
11-20
21-30
... and so on...
```

Right now, I have a very messy code..

What I have done is mapped

```
1-10 :=> 0
11-20:=> 1
..and on..
```

So I have defined buckets where bucket 0 has range 1-10, bucket 1 has range 11-20 and so on.

And the code is:

```
for ele in data:
    bucket_id = get_bucket_id(ele)
    freq_dict[bucket_id] +=1
```

`get_bucket_id` is a big `if else` code..

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you should be able to easily calculate the bin rather than use a big else if

Comment: What do you want to do with 10.5? It is neither between 1-10, nor 11-20... Assuming you want buckets like (0,10], (10,20]..., though, that should be as easy as `int(math.ceil(x/10.))`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `Counter` and compute the bucket using integer division.

```
from collections import Counter

freq = Counter()
for x in data:
    freq[(x - 1) // 10] += 1
```

Note that this maps values less than one to `-1`. When dealing with not-strictly positive data, you'll actually want to use ranges 1-9, 10-19, etc.

Comment: Slightly shorter (and IMHO more readble): `freq=Counter((x-1)//10 for x in data)`.

Comment: `freq = Counter((int(round(x)) - 1) // 10 + 1 for x in data)` will give correct bucket numbers...

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), which tabulates the frequencies at which elements in your data appear in a set of intervals (bins). It returns the counts in each bin and the rightmost edge of each bin:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [0.1,0.2,1,5,100]
>>> hist, bin_edges = np.histogram( data )
>>> hist
array([4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
>>> bin_edges
array([   0.1 ,   10.09,   20.08,   30.07,   40.06,   50.05,   60.04,
         70.03,   80.02,   90.01,  100.  ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `len` and `filter`:

```
c = []
for l, u in [(1, 10), (11, 20), (21, 30)]: # ...
    c.append(len(filter(lambda x: l <= x <= u, values)))
```

Comment: For `object of type 'filter' has no len()` error:    `c.append(sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x: l <= x <= u, values)))`

Comment: @K.Symbol `len(filter(...))` won't work in Python 3. You could wrap the `filter(...)` call in a `list()` call (i.e. `len(list(filter(...)))`), but you're probably better of using one of the other solutions.

Comment: list is simple but takes extra memory, so I used sum since I have 1 million values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` and [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module here:

```
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> lis = range(0, 101, 10)
>>> l = [0.1, 0.2, 1, 5, 100, 11]
>>> c = Counter(bisect_left(lis, item) for item in l)
>>> c
Counter({1: 4, 10: 1, 2: 1})
>>> [c[i] for i in xrange(1, 11)]
[4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```